# How to write plain BigInteger in Spring controller

Tags: json, spring, kotlin, jackson

I need to return BigInteger from Spring controller in numeric format (such as 354736184430273859332531) instead of for example 2.2311485309166910602366e+23 which is default behavior.

I have tried including both: `spring.jackson.serialization.write-bigdecimal-as-plain=true` and 
`spring.jackson.generator.write-bigdecimal-as-plain=true` in application.properties

My object which I'm returning looks like this:

```
data class ProductOutputDTO(
    val token: BigInteger,
    val product: BigInteger
)
```

And controller code:

```
@RestController
class Product {

    @PostMapping("/product")
    fun product(@RequestBody input: ProductInputDTO): ProductOutputDTO
            = ProductOutputDTO(input.token, input.a * input.b)

}
```

Comment: How are you returning the data to the client from the controller? Are you converting it to json or some other type?

Comment: @RayHunter I have updated question to include controller code. I'm returning json to client.

Comment: You will want to probably convert the BigInteger to a json string since the precision on a json number is probably not what you want. Or you can convert the BigInteger to a java string, then your controller will handle the java string to json string for you.

Comment: I've tried converting it tostring, but json output is then like `"product":"35622"`, but it must be `"product":35622`

Comment: Then you will have to deal with the precision that JSON number has or use something that is the same in your code as the precision as JSON number.  Numbers in JSON must be an integer or a floating point. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159#section-6

Answer (score 0):

Change your `ProductOutputDTO` to be something like the following example:

```
data class ProductOutputDTO(
    val token: String,
    val product: String
)
```

Then change your code that creates the `ProductOutputDTO` to convert the BigIntegers to Strings.

The problem you are running into is that the JSON Number precision is not as precise as the BigInteger.

Comment: The requested format in task description is for example:
```
{
  "token": 1498723,
  "product": 11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
}
```
But if I changed `ProductOutputDTO.product` to string the numbers are in quotes

Comment: Are you writing the consumer code on the other side? How would the consumer of the JSON handle the product value? The consumer is bound by the same limitations of the JSON number type. If you kept it as exponential format, then the consumer can convert it to what it needs to be.

Comment: This is task for studies and probably this task will be verified with curl as teacher's script will invoke pre-defined command and watch to pre-defined result

Comment: If you are going to use JSON Number as a data type, then you will have to work with that data type. Since you are using spring you could produce XML instead of JSON and see how your converter works with XML data. That might give you the results that you want, unless you are required to use JSON.

Comment: I'm required to use JSON. There is an another example of what JSON I must generate: `{
  "token": 1234567890,
  "product": 22230581231342048010971200514544
}`